# Change link behavior for non-existent files / broken links

Tags: apache, http, iis, browser, server

When users click on a link to a file (eg: csv, zip), there are two things that could happen:

1. If the file exists: it starts downloading (the web page does not change).
2. If the file does not exist: the user will be redirected to a 404 page (default or custom).

If when the file exists there's no redirection (or to be proper, the user doesn't get the idea of), why is there a redirection when the file doesn't exist?

I understand that when the browser gets a 404 response code, it needs to somehow display it to the user, but shouldn't it take into consideration the event that triggered the request? It is not the same to type an incorrect URL in the address bar than to click on a link. Wouldn't the browser showing an alert and remaining on the same page be a more "appropriate behavior"?

It would be relatively easy to create some back-end (or front-end) script that checks all the links, verifies if the files exists (or not), and then replaces the behavior accordingly. But is there something different that can be done? is it possible to (programatically) change the browser's settings so it doesn't redirect if the file doesn't exist? Or have the server return an HTTP code different than 404 (maybe in the 400s family) to cause such behavior?